# How to programmatically deselect UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` which I can click on, and edit the contents of. I am running code when the UITextField is pressed by using:

```
[personalCountryLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(countryPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
```

This presents another view controller. However, when I click the back button, the UITextField is still selected, so the text runs again, sending me back to the view controller.

I use the code:

```
textField.enabled = false;
```

and

```
textField.enabled = true;
```

to respectively turn off and on the editing of the `UITextField`, but doing this in succession does not unselect the `UITextField`.

How can I therefore programmatically deselect the `UITextField` (i.e, where the line cursor is no longer blinking).

Answer (score 5):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you just want:

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: I tried this, but it hasn't worked unfortunately. If I run the code and comment out the subsequent segue, all it does is stop the cursor from blinking. However, the UITextField is still selected, and the user can still enter text if they enter values on their keyboard.

Comment: Does the keyboard disappear? This is the standard iOS means of disconnecting a keyboard from a UITextField.

Comment: Yes, when I have the keyboard turned on, and click on the UITextField, the keyboard remains there. Logs show the code is definitely being run.

Comment: Isaac, are you running this on iPad?

Comment: Also, are you positive that `textField` is not `nil` when you send it the `resignFirstResponder` message?

Comment: Aaron - I'm not running this on iPad - It's on an iPhone 6 simulator. And I did have a textFieldShouldEndEditing method which may have caused the textField to be nil. Running the above code now works mainly as intended. However, an issue still remains where if I click on another UITextField, then click on the text field which runs the resignFirstResponder code, the keyboard does not hide, and persists when the new view controller is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

/*  Programmatically deselect the Uitextfiels below this Code */

```
UITextField *txtDeselect = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+20, self.view.frame.origin.y+20, self.view.frame.size.width-40, 40)];
    [txtDeselect setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [txtDeselect setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [txtDeselect setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [txtDeselect setText:@"Email"];
    txtDeselect.enabled = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:txtDeselect];
```

Comment: I don't get it. Does this work? Would you explain?

Answer (score 0):

did you set outlet & delegate of UITextField in your view controller ?
why you use UItextfield  for this ?

i recommend you use one of this before presenting new view controller  :

**option 1 :**

```
[youtextfield resignFirstResponder];
```

//please sure you outlet connected & ....

you can call this on your viewWillAppear

**option 2 :**

```
[self.view endEditing:YES]; // this regularly
happend after present another VC)
```

**you shouldn't use shouldEndEditing**